# Deploy Angular-App with original files

Tags: javascript, angular, deployment, npm, angular-cli

I have an Angular application which is build with the Angular-CLI. I want to deploy this project to a Spring-Microservice. When i deploy the build, which generated with the cli-command `ng build --prod` the application works fine.

But: I want to deploy the Original files including my typescript files to the Microservice so i can see where my console-logs come from (which line in which file, just the same as when i run the application locally with "ng serve").

A few months ago, i had a Angular-project which i started with the [Angular Quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart). I ran this project with NPM (commands: **npm install** and **npm start**). This project transpiled the typescript-files to javascript, and for this reason, this project is deployable and works fine.

But my CLI-project dont do that, so it is not deployable.

How can I deploy my application as described?

Comment: Guess you're looking for `ng build --prod`, then you just need to upload `dist` folder on your server.

By the way, you will still know where the error is from, because of `.map` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this presentation, I generated an Angular project with CLI, generated a REST server using Spring Boot, and showed how to deploy this Angular app under the Spring server https://youtu.be/k8r76d8QzXs?t=870.

To be able to debug your Typescript code with prod bundles, use add the --sourcemaps option:

```
ng build -prod --sourcemaps true
```

Comment: Glad you liked it :)

Answer (score 1):

When you build an Angular project with the production flag the Angular CLI creates and the sourcemaps (you can identify them  from their extension .map.js) of the minified Javascript files.

The easiest way to go is to deploy all the generated files.
When you open the developer tools of the browser to debug them the browser recognize them, and generates the unminified Javascript files. You can find them on Sources Panel. (e.g. Chrome)

So you don't need the original Typescript files

I am not sure, if you can see on your console when you log something, the exact file and line where the original code is, from a minified Javascript file.